# Objections to use an RCA connector for antenna in broadcast FM receiver

Tags: antenna, frequency-modulation, rca

Due to budget & space restrictions, I am thinking about replacing a PCB BNC connector used to attach an external FM antenna. It seems to me an RCA connector could be an option, given its good shielding, low impedance and the (relatively) low frequencies involved. But I was unable to find better arguments for & against it in my searches, or any examples of anyone using it. Would it have a good (or at least acceptable) performance? If not, any recommendations?
BTW, the antenna at the other end is the typical monopole, 100R.

Comment: I imagine it would have acceptable performance. IIRC I used to have a hi-fi radio that did exactly that.

Comment: RCA type connectors are in general not used for handling RF frequencies, so there is no guarantee the impedence will be acceptable. Some specs. of the connectors would need to be checked.

Comment: And the FM frequency is?

Comment: @user3169: Actually, a standard RCA connector is a surprisingly good match for 50-ohm coax. Hams discovered this ages ago, and used them for both receiving and low-power transmitting antenna connections.

Comment: @Andyaka: The commercial FM broadcast band is in the VHF band at 88 - 108 MHz (in the USA).

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes I know!! But what frequency is the OP talking about?

Comment: @Andyaka in my country the FM range is a bit wider than in the US, but not that much. The range given by Dave is perfectly fine as a parameter.

Comment: @fceconel you are actually referring to the "broadcast FM range" - I was trying to establish if you were meaning this or maybe a private or ham-radio frequency (or maybe something else like satellite reception). Your question was unclear, that is why I asked.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry, now I got it. Correcting.

Comment: RCA connectors are often found in older equipment running up to the VHF range. They seem to work okay but I've not personally swept or tested them at those frequencies. I suspect they will work just fine.

Comment: The normal common means of connecting video games to television sets used to be to use a 75-ohm cable with RCA connectors to connect the computer to a switchbox which would then output 300 ohm split lead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be fine. RCA connectors are found inside some TVs. I have this on 88-108 broadcast FM, and without doing measurements it is fine. Measurements weren't done because I didn't have access to suitable VHF test gear 25 years ago. The plug is still fine.